# AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am working with data that comes in similar format to this in insights. Sometimes the value of J may be missing and I want to set the value as the value of B if this is the case. Is there any way to do conditional logic similar to this on data in CloudWatch Insights? I have explored `ispresent()` but cannot figure out how to do the conditional logic.

Example:

| B | J |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 |  |

for the last I would like to set the data equal in J to 2 when I run the query.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to use `coalesce(J, B)` which won't set the J to 2 but can be assigned to a new field (e.g. `fields coalesce(J, B) as newB` that can be used for display or additional logic. `coalesce` takes 2+ arguments and returns the first value that isn't blank.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html (search for coalesce)